# php, mysql, Inserting data using loop

Tags: php, mysql

I receiving APIs data which I have to store into database.
I have to use loop because I can't know how many Items the customer will put into the basket.
For more information, please take a look of my sample example . Depends  of the loop I manage to store only the first or last item...
Any help it will be appreciated.

```
<?php

$data = array
  (
  array("Item1"),
  array("Item2"),
  array("Item3"),
  array("Item4"),

  );

$count = count($data);    

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$x = 0;
while($x <= $count-1) {
    $mytest = $data[$x][0];
echo $mytest;
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (mytest)
VALUES ('$mytest')";


  $x++;
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: you never told us what isn't working the way you want it to.

Comment: you run the querry outside the loop, only the last item will be iserted

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner Now I'm storing only the last item (Item4).
And I need to store all of them.

Comment: To loop over an array use `foreach`, not `while`.

Comment: And why do you write `$x <= $count-1` instead of the more idiomatic `$x < $count`?

Comment: The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

    foreach (array_expression as $value)
        statement
    foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
        statement

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop is always better than while when iterating an Array.

The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable. There are two syntaxes:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement

foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

Solution to your problem :

```
foreach($data as $val) {
    echo $val;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (mytest) VALUES ('$mytest')"; 
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```